# PHP : Check if the URL contains slash at the end

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm using model view controller and in my URL I need to have slash at the ending of the url. How to check if it is having a slash or not?

```
http://localhost/tabulation/event/event_name/<--I need to check this slash

$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
$url = rtrim($url. '/');
$url = explode('/', $url);
//if($url[2] has no backslashes then execute the condition
```

Comment: Your `rtrim` is incorrect. Don't concatenate the trailing character(s) are the second parameter. You then could just append a `/` cause you know the trailing slash was removed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this by getting the whole url first then get the last character

```
$getWholeUrl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."";

//The output would be 
/*
  http://localhost/tabulation/event/event_name/
*/

if(substr($getWholeUrl , -1)=='/'){
    //Add your condition here

}
```

Answer (score 4):

For instance like this:

```
if(strrev($url)[0]==='/') {
 //  the last character in the url is a slash
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many possibilities for it :

has slash :

```
$url{strlen($url)-1} == '/'; (same as $url[strlen($url)-1] == '/';)

strrpos($a,'/') === strlen($a) -1
```